# Is there a vb.net program that can modify its code at runtime?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible? Self modifying codes based on users choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - see prior two answers.

but don't, unless *there is no other way*; debugging will be a nightmare

consider plug-ins instead, if possible

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but complicated; look at the classes in the [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) namespace.

However, you can probably do something simpler; please tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I don't know yet what I'm trying to do, I'm still just asking if its possible. But if I start coding, I'll definitely have an answer to your question. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. Reflection allows code to be compiled on-the-fly and executed.